# If UMAP clustering result of the dataset is bad, is it un-classifiable?

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset

I made a dataset for my own research, which has about 30,000 datas.

Each data has 20 floats as input and 4 classes.

The training with any network model were bad(always overfit) so I drew a UMAP and got the result like following :

[image]

Here class 0 (dark blue ) is distributed on everywhere, which represents "class-0 data should be ignored during process".

When ignoring 99% of class-0 data, the UMAP becomes :

[image]

As you can see, the result is nice.

Since class-0 datasets are very important so that I cannot totally remove them .

In this case, what should I do to get the optimal deep learning result ?

Please tell me any solutions with smallest possibility and I will deeply thank you.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? Have you tried a clustering method after employing UMAP for dimensionality reduction?

Comment: @Shasa  not yet. I just adjusted a simple dense-layer deep learning model to get somehow-good-but-unsatisfying accuracy and still finding ways.

Comment: I see. Do you use unsupervised or supervised UMAP? Supervised versions usually perform better in clustering.

Comment: @Shasa I guess it is unsupervised ver since it gives me same result no matter I imbue them labels or not. can you please give me where to implement superviesd UMAP ?

Comment: You can pass labels using "target=label" inside the fit_transform.

Comment: @Shasa can you tell me where I should add it ? I am using umap module of here : https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html#digits-data

Comment: To `reducer.fit(digits.data)`. First, introduce a list of labels and then pass that as `reducer.fit(digits.data, y=label_list)`

Comment: You can also use `reducer.fit_transform(digits.data, y=label_list)`. It all depends on how you want to perform `fit` and `transform`.

Comment: @Shasa It really helped me a lot. Thank you so much . Is it possible to save the clustering parameter and re-use it ?

Comment: Glad to hear that my suggestion helped you. What particular parameter do you have in mind? in principle, Umap results are reproducible if you set the random_state fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Shasa mention in comment, I could make my umap result better.

I just added
`reducer.fit(digits.data, y=label_list)`
on UMAP transform code.